# Laravel 5.3 Route in template showing Route Not Defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

i am updating my application from laravel 5.2 to 5.3. Most of the things seems to work fine.

But i dont know what is happening but when i am trying to define route in anchor tag, its not working. I have done something similar to this:

```
<a href="{{route('backend.pages.index')}}" class="nav-link ">
     <span class="title">All Pages</span>
</a>
```

Its showing error `Route [backend.pages.index] not defined.`. Here is how the created the route.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
     Route::resource('backend/pages','Backend\PagesController');
});
```

I have a template called 'mainmenu.blade.php' in which i have use this route. This mainmenu is called in main structure through `@include('layouts.backend.backendstructure.mainmenu')`.

Is routing method is changed in laravel 5.3? Or is there any mistake from my side?

Thank you!(Advance)

Comment: Do `php artisan route:list` and paste the output here.

Comment: Yes @linuxartisan i got my answer through listing the routes. I guess the problem was with `backend` it does not needed any more.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is

`{{route('backend.pages.index')}}`

instead use

```
<a href="{{route('backend/pages')}}" class="nav-link ">
     <span class="title">All Pages</span>
</a>
```

The route is defined as `backend/pages`. To return view add a method in PagesController and return the view there.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
     Route::resource('backend/pages','Backend\PagesController@dummymethod');
});
```

Dummy method

```
public function dummymethod
{
    return view('backend.pages.index');
}
```

**Edit**

I think you're looking for something like this

`Route::resource('backend/pages','Backend\PagesController', ['names' => ['index' => 'backend.pages.index']]);`

Check the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: I guess the way you are explaining the things are quite wrong i guess. I just try to create a new project, and try to execute the same what i done above. `Route::get('backend/pages','Backend\PagesController@dummymethod');` is should be like this?

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this `Route::resource('backend/pages', 'Backend\PagesController',
                ['names' => ['index' => 'backend.pages.index']]);`

Comment: Yes this method worked. But earlier we never did that! This is so strange!

Answer (score 1):

You should write your `code` like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('backend/pages')}} " class="nav-link ">
     <span class="title">All Pages</span>
</a>
```

or like this:

```
<a href="{{ url('backend/pages') }}" class="nav-link ">
     <span class="title">All Pages</span>
</a>
```

Comment: What about the edit method, when we need to pass a parameter?

Comment: And everything seems to be working fine, till Laravel version 5.2

Comment: I tried changing but still seems to have the same issue `Route [backend/pages/index] not defined` or `Route [backend/pages] not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  <a href="/backend/pages" class="nav-link ">
  <span class="title">All Pages</span>
  </a>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing

Comment: Sure this will work. But i am not sure whats wrong with putting the way i am putting currently? Because it should be working fine. It was working great in version 5.2 of laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can try link with URL to like, I use in following manner

```
 <a href="{{URL::to('backend/pages')}}" class="nav-link ">
  <span class="title">All Pages</span>
  </a>
```